# How to programmatically create a level-list?

Tags: android, 360-degrees

i'm getting images of a product dynamically from a server. These images are actually of different angles of the same product.I want to create a 360 degree of view from these images in android like in shopping websites. Layer-list is an option but it cannot load images dynamically is there any otherway to do this in android.

```
 <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_01" />
<item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_02" />
<item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_03" />
<item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_04" />
<item android:maxLevel="4" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_05" />
</level-list>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Use `picasso.get().rotate(360).into`

In case you don't know .. 
`picasso` is third party library